# Need suggestion regarding stripe integration

Tags: stripe-payments, strip, stripe-connect

I am making an app which have internal wallet, and user can withdraw amount from that wallet to their bank account. I am planing to use stripe connect account for each user and store user's bank information there and then create transfer to deposit amount to users bank account from wallet.

I am planing create one account for my platform from which transfer amount will be debited.

But user can also buy something from site and he can only pay using card and not able to buy something from wallet balance.

My question is, Should I create stripe customer also for each user and charge that user using card details? or Is there any better way to deal with this? Can I store user's card info as an external account in stripe connect and charge my user using stripe connect?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use Account Debits for this https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits otherwise yes store their card as a customer.

Comment: Thanks @koopajah. I'll check above URL and figure out best solution